# What does "drills, code reds" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Senator, these drills, code reds, active shooters, they've been a part of my life for as long as I can remember.
>   <sub>[Stoneman students' questions to lawmakers and the NRA at the CNN town hall](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/02/22/politics/cnn-town-hall-full-video-transcript/index.html)</sub>

See also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaLh74eXTDo) at 31:40.

Does "drills, code reds" mean alarms (firm alarms etc.)?

Reference I found:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Red

Thanks.

Comment: Code systems are ad hoc. There is no one meaning. It only works if you are familiar with the specific system of codes being talked about. And you haven't provided us that context.

Comment: Sorry. The context is:  https://edition.cnn.com/2018/02/22/politics/cnn-town-hall-full-video-transcript/index.html  and this  quote  is from Ryan Deitsch  or video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaLh74eXTDo   at 31:40

Comment: There is plenty of context here.   Anyone involved in law enforcement or even a half-wit member of the public (like me) knows that nowadays schools, universities, businesses etc. have drills to practice what to do when shooters show up. drills are practice drills, to escape a shooter. Code red is typically cop talk for some terrible emergency.  Code red and drills are not fire drills. They are drills to escape shooters. You hear code red in movies and TV shows all the time. Also in hospitals.

Answer (score 3):

From context, Deitsch (the speaker) is talking about practices related to school shootings. The town hall is being held in Florida, where ["code red"](https://www.nbcmiami.com/news/local/Education-on-6-Code-Red-Drills-Prepare-Students-for-Active-Shooter-Situations-480871741.html) seems to be a standard term for an [immediate threat](https://www.asumag.com/crisis-amp-disaster-planningmanagement/security-solutions-colors-crisis) to students and staff. "Drills" in this context would refer to a scheduled practice for a code red situation, and of course an active shooter is a specific, real code red scenario.

This is a good example of the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(writing)#Rhetoric_and_public_speaking) in rhetoric: Deitsch is using three closely linked examples of what modern students are facing today in ascending order of seriousness (preparing for threats, real threats of any kind, real threat of a school shooter). Using three specific examples instead of a more vague umbrella term drives home the idea of these things being pervasive in his life and the lives of others.

Comment: code red is a standard term in many places and in many institutions but I uveed you.

Comment: @Alan. Thanks for your answer and I googled "umbrella term" and get it. But "xx drives home the idea of xxxx" do you mean "deliver the idea perfectly"?  thx^^

Comment: @Lambie I try to figure out what "uve" is short for but only found "u(you) have". Could you tell me? Thx too

Comment: @RebeccaChung It means up voted.